# Восстановление файла с помощью ассемблера

Tags: ассемблер

Добрый день. Лаба по ассемблеру.
Задание: Составить программу быстрого восстановления файла (Аналог QU). 
У меня ступор.. Есть соображения с чего начать?)

p.s. использую компилятор TASM.

Comment: Что такое QU, QuickUnerase? :)




Лучше спросить у преподавателя, что имелось в виду. Возможно, первую буковку имени файла надо восстановить (в FAT файлы стираются путём изменения первой буквы). Возможно, Вам надо самому научиться портить файлы (допустим, байты местами переставлять), а потом восстанавливать.

Comment: да, QuickUnerase! 
Хорошо, так и поступлю. Спасибо)